# Reading an Array List (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, list, input

I am trying to take input from a user and then sort that input into an array.  The input must either be an int, double, or string.  All I have right now is a loop asking for the input of the user.

How do I read/identify the input and store it into its proper `ArrayList`?

What I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class userInput {

public static void main(String [] args){
     ArrayList<String> randomTextlist = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<Double> doublelist = new ArrayList<Double>();
     ArrayList<Integer> intlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     boolean input = true;

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 while (input){
      System.out.print("Input string, int, or double.");
      intlist.add(scan.next());
 }
```

Am I heading in the right direction? If so how do you suggest making sure that the input is put into their proper ArrayLists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    ArrayList<String> randomTextlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> doublelist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Integer> intlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean input = true;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (input){
        System.out.print("Input string, int, or double.");
        //exit loop case: input false, or how would you exit the loop?
        if (scan.hasNextBoolean()){
            break;
        }

        if (scan.hasNextDouble()){
            doublelist.add(scan.nextDouble());
        }
        else if (scan.hasNextInt()){
            intlist.add(scan.nextInt());
        }
        else{
            randomTextlist.add(scan.next());
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(doublelist);
    System.out.println(doublelist);
    Collections.sort(intlist);
    System.out.println(intlist);
    Collections.sort(randomTextlist);
    System.out.println(randomTextlist);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This will keep collecting until you type "q" and then print all the results in each `ArrayList`. You can modify it from there to suit your needs.

```
while (input) {
    System.out.println("Input string, int, or double:");
    if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
        intlist.add(scan.nextInt());
    } else if(scan.hasNextDouble()) {
        doublelist.add(scan.nextDouble());
    } else {
        String str = scan.next();
        if(str.equals("q")) 
            break;

        randomTextlist.add(str);
    }
}

// sort the lists
Collections.sort(intlist);
Collections.sort(doublelist);
Collections.sort(randomTextlist);

// print the lists
System.out.println(intlist);
System.out.println(doublelist);
System.out.println(randomTextlist);
```

Answer (score 2):

a number like 245 is integer and also double so you must add it to `intList` and `doubleList`
but a number like 235.35 is only double so you must add it only to `doubleList`
other inputs (not fully numeric inputs ) are not int or double so you must add them to `randomTextlist`

now how we can detect an input is which one of them ?
it's simple using `try/catch` statements.how ?

first check if input is `Integer` or not ? if it does'nt be `Integer`, when you try to parse it, it throws `NumberFormatException` so you can detect that input is not `Integer`.

in `catch` statement you must check if input is `Double` or not, if it does'nt be ; it throws `NumberFormatException` as above 
so input isn't `Double`, now we are sure that it belongs to `randomTextlist`

but if it was `Integer` you must add it to int and double list,
and so on
now watch this code ,so that you understand what i'm trying to tell you !

```
   while (input) {
        String next = scan.next();
        try {
            /*
             check if input is integer or not,
             if it not ,  it throws NumberFormatException
             */
            int n = Integer.parseInt(next);

            // if input was integer it does'nt throw any exception 
            // so add input to your lists
            intlist.add(n);
            doublelist.add(new Double(n));

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            try {
                 /*
                 check if input is double or not,
                 if it not , it throws NumberFormatException
                 */
                double n = Double.parseDouble(next);

                // like above there is no exception so input is double 
                // and we add it to doublelist
                doublelist.add(n);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                // after two NumberFormatExceptions we are sure that  
                // input isn't integer or double so add it to randomTextlist
                randomTextlist.add(next);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to figure out what type of data you have.

Try to parse as an Integer first, then as a Double and default to a String if all else fails. Untested example:

```
String scannedValue = scan.next();
try {
    intlist.add(Integer.parseInt(scannedValue));
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
    try {
        doublelist.add(Double.parseDouble(scannedValue));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
        randomTextlist.add(scannedValue);
    }
}
```

Now for the sorted list stuff. Currently, you are just adding the value to the list.

Since `Integer`, `Double` and `String` all implement `Comparable`, you can use the `sort` method on `Collections` to sort your lists:

```
Collections.sort(randomTextlist);
Collections.sort(doublelist);
Collections.sort(intlist);
```

Comment: So use an if statement to to parse?

Comment: First off...do you actually need three ArrayLists. By default the ArrayList accepts Object.